# Transform RGB-Map to CMYK (qgis, opensource tools)

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, colortable

I want to print a map I made with qgis. For the print I need CMYK-colors but the print-composers pdf-output is RGB. How can I convert the RGB-map/-pdf to CMYK?

Comment: Normally, the printer should handle the conversion.  Do you need specific colours to display a certain way?  

Have you checked out www.kuler.com?  You can convert RGB to CMYK fairly easily.

Comment: Have you tried to export from qgis as bitmap and import into scribsu dtp (with colormangement enabled settings!) and export from scribus as pdf/x3 ?

Comment: addendum and correction to my above comment: for workflow with scribus look here: http://scribus-forum.de/discussion/rgb-cmyk-umwandeln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend ghostscript - it's available for free both on Linux and Windows.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418268/script-or-some-other-means-to-convert-rgb-to-cmyk-in-pdf for the solution.